# A using Trim() in linq makes it run slower

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

i'm doing a Linq example for some class i need to give to some army guys studying C#. they gave me a database and asked me to make some queries, for example

```
ArmedVehicles.Where(x => x.vCommandingUnit.Equals("North"))
.Select(x => new {
  vCommander = x.vCommander,
  vLocation = x.vLocBase,
  vType = x.vType});
```

The problem is that the fields `vCommander` and `vLocBase` are padded with blanks, and when i use `.Trim()` for them then it takes significantly more time (about 5-8 seconds more) and i can't show them that slow example.

of course when i'll talk to them i'll say to fix the database, but for now i need a faster Linq so my example won't make me look bad

Comment: Is there a way to pad x.vCommander and vLocBase with spaces and compare it to that?

Comment: Why don't you do the Trim() before/when you fetch them (SQL?) and then you don't have to do it on the linQ

Comment: You know that you can do `vCommandingUnit == "North"` and it will be equivalent, right?

Comment: Try `TrimEnd` if you only need to trim right. It could be a little faster.

Comment: The place to filter is the database. Else every application would have to deal with this tact

Comment: As a sidenote, how many records are you loading, and are you using Entity Framework or LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: @xanatos Linq-to-SQL, and i'm loading some thousands to about 14,000 (i have some databases, i don't need to show it on all of them, but they might ask me on a specific). TrimEnd helped a bit, and i'll use it if there is nothing else, but i hope there is more

Comment: @NoIdeaForName If you don't have to modify the records (you only want to show them), then set [ObjectTrackingEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.objecttrackingenabled.aspx) to false. Note that this will disable the `DeferredLoadingEnabled`.

Comment: @NoIdeaForName And it would be better if you could give use the exact query that is being executed by SQL, by using the `Log` property of the `DataContext`

Comment: The vCommander and vLocBase elements are not used as predicates in the query, so I would defer Trim() until after the query was realized and the results were actually going to be presented.

Comment: @xanatos TrimEnd along with the rest of the help you gave helped lower the time needed for the LINQ, write it in an answer so i can accept it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your text is space-padded only on the right, you could use `TrimEnd()` instead of `Trim()`.

Please remember that loading 14k records in the `DataContext` is nearly always a bad idea. Normally you can disable the object tracking if you don't need to modify them (see the [ObjectTrackingEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.objecttrackingenabled.aspx) property of the `DataContext` object.

Answer (score 0):

Stores the `VCommander` and `VLocaBase` fields in the database in the format you need to retrieve it (without padding).

Comment: as you could read i got the Database from the army, i can't change them because i'm not the DBA of the army.... just been called to show some LINQ

Comment: Ok, then we need an other option. Do VCommander and VLocBase needs to be available immidiately, or can it it be implement is Lazy so it it slows when you acces to property? This saves time when you don't use all properties for all elements.